# Dynamic paths for laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant

While [building multi-tenancy packages for Laravel 5](http://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant) I had to find out how to make the paths and namespaces dynamic.

This would involve:

- views; adding a template directory dynamically that is available in the root namespace
- lang; adding a language directory dynamically that is available in the root namespace
- routes; adding a routes file dynamically
- config; merging additional configuration files from a dynamic location
- vendor; allowing custom vendors and packages to be available from a dynamic location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## views

Using a [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) you can use the following in your `boot()` method for views to be available in the root namespace (`view('your-view')` instead of `view('package::your-view')`):

```
$this->app['view']->addLocation('/your/new/location');
```

## lang

Using a [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) you can use the following in your `boot()` method where `$path` is the new path for your root namespace translations:

```
$app->bindShared('translation.loader', function($app) use ($path)
{
      return new \Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader($app['files'], $path);
});
$app->bindShared('translator', function($app)
{
      $translator = new \Illuminate\Translation\Translator($app['translation.loader'], $app['config']['app.locale']);
      $translator->setFallback($app['config']['app.fallback_locale']);
      return $translator;
});
```

## routes

Routes is by far the easiest. Simply include them using a `require_once` or by using the Laravel method: `\File::requireOnce()`.

## config

I used a directory that would allow a tenant to overrule core configs. Please advice there are no security nor sanity checks here so access should be limited.

Using a [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) you can use the following in your `boot()` method

```
 foreach (\File::allFiles('/path/to/configs') as $path) {
       $key = \File::name($path);
       $app['config']->set($key, array_merge(require $path, $app['config']->get($key, [])));
 }
```

This will merge existing configurations by overruling their values with the provided config files.

## vendor

Really interesting is the possibility to use dynamically loaded classes.  In order to do this you will need to use the `ClassLoader` `addDirectories()` method in your [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers)

```
\Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader::addDirectories(['/path/to/vendors']);
```

## additional considerations

The above code can be implemented using service providers. In order for a server provider to work you **must** add them to the `config/app.php` file under the `providers` array. Not doing so will not enable any of the code in the service provider.