# Multi tenancy and multiple domains Laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant

I'm building an SaaS application in Laravel-5.  Basically, I want our client to be able to point their domain to our name servers and effectively the application will load their website template (which will vary from client to client).  It will also allow our clients' members to login to their account through their website and load all of their personal details.

Is this possible in Laravel-5 and can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to support multi tenancy in laravel.

- Using [middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165312/dynamic-middleware-for-laravel-5/30165313#30165313) you can dynamically mutate the request object to modify behavior of the application.
- By modifying the [path locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116617/dynamic-paths-for-laravel-5) you can then change where views and almost anything else is loaded from.
- [Landlord](https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord), a single database multi-tenancy package for Laravel & Lumen 5.2+.
- Another proven package is [Tenanti](https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti) which handles custom database connections and even observes models to track changes to different database connections.
- I'm currently [maintaining](https://laravel-tenancy.com) a multi tenancy package for Laravel that allows complete division of responsibility for databases, files etc while maintaining a system connection for system wide settings and hostname setup.

Deprecated:

- If you only want to have one database that stores all tenants, you might be interested in [AuraEQ](https://github.com/AuraEQ/laravel-multi-tenant), I'm not sure there should be others. Is now Landlord.

Comment: I've tried installing AuraEQ but can't manage to get it working with the latest version of Laravel.  It says that it supports v 4.2+ however, I do not think this is the case.  Is it possible to use orchestra/tenanti instead?

Comment: Yes. Tenanti I forgot.